# Can MKS Integrity integrate with other source control tools? (SVN, Git...)

Tags: git, svn, version-control, mercurial, mks-integrity

My boss is interested in using MKS Integrity for bug tracking, feature requests, Wiki documentation and so on. However, we currently use Subversion, and he doesn't want to force us devs to use a version control system that we don't like.

Is is possible to integrate a different version control program into MKS Integrity? I'm particularly interested in SVN, Git, Mercurial and Bazaar. If you've tried mixing tools like this before, I'd love to hear about your experiences.

**Update:** As the question answerer answered, there are integrations for ClearCase, Perforce and Subversion. However, there definitely does not seem to be any integration yet created for Mercurial or Git. At the same time, creating an integration seems to require something on the order of about 500 lines of (Perl) code, so creating an integration for one of those version control systems is not out of the question if you really want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, MKS can integrate with other version control providers and has done so with Perforce, CC and Subversion for specific customers.

Comment: That's great news! Thanks for your help! One last question: what about Git? Any integration with that?

Answer (score 2):

MKS RM does have a command line interface, therefore creating a set of hook scripts for the VCS to interact with MKS RM is fairly straight forward.

This is something I am curently investigating, so saw this question, here.

I am fairly sure that integrating Mercurial/Git/SVN/other would create a more smoothly functioning interaction with MKS RM than the interaction between MKS RM and MKS SI

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I can't offer informed opinion on the combination of MKS with those SCMs but I'd like to contribute.

If your first concern is a SCM that the developers like then choose that first and then find a tracker that works with it as a secondary concern.

Answer (score 0):

likewise I have no experience with MKS integrity but i'd be surprised if you couldn't use any of those VCS with it. All of them allow arbitrary code to be executed from hooks before and after their functions, so it merely needs to be scriptable in some way. try the [mercurial book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html) for a tutorial on writing hooks for mercurial if MKS doesn't already provide this

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if MKS would be allow to plugin different VCS. They provide a full ALM solution and it is wrapped around their on version control system. So you have different streams, changesets etc. 
I doubt you can jsut switch the underlying version control system.

For SVN are a lot of alternatives which combine wiki and some tracking tools, free and commercial, a small list(please add more in comments!):

- [redmine](http://www.redmine.org) (free)
- [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) (free)
- [collabnet TeamForge](http://www.open.collab.net/products/ctf/) (commercial)
- [polarion ALM](http://www.polarion.com) (commercial)